# How do I center a PDFSelection within the overall View?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ios11, pdfkit

I'm trying to use `PDFKit` with Swift in iOS 11. I have a `PDFView` and a `PDFSelection` that I would like to scroll to, zoom in to, and center within the overall `view`. I'm able to scroll to the `PDFView`'s `currentSelection` with the function `scrollSelectionToVisible(_ sender: Any?)`, but the selection always appear in the upper left of the screen.

**How can I reposition the page to make the selection be at the center?**

**I know a `PDFSelection` has a `bounds(for: PDFPage)` function that returns a `CGRect`, in page space. But I don't know what to do with it beyond that.**

What I currently see with after `pdfView.scrollSelectionToVisible()` (`currentSelection` in green upper left):
[image]

What I'd like to see (`currentSelection` in center of `view`):
[image]

This:

```
pdfView.currentSelection = selection
pdfView.scrollSelectionToVisible(nil)
```

And this:

```
pdfView.currentSelection = selection
let pdfPage = pdfView.document!.page(at: 0)!
let cgRect = pdfView.currentSelection!.bounds(for: pdfPage)
pdfView.go(to: cgRect, on: pdfPage)
```

are producing the same effect (the effect in the first image).

Answer (score 1):

After you create the PDFviewer center the view like this

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: viewFA.view.bounds) 
pdfView.center.y = viewFA.view.center.y - 100
```